# Bash overwrites the first line when using custom PS1 prompt

Tags: bash, shell, prompt, bashrc

My question is similar, but different to, [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49891/bash-overwrites-the-first-line-ps1-bash-prompt).

I have created a custom PS1 in my `.bashrc`, as follows:

```
STARTCOLOR='\e[0;36m';
ENDCOLOR="\e[0m"
export PS1="\n$STARTCOLOR\u@\h:\! <\t> \w\n\$ $ENDCOLOR"
```

Which looks like so (but with color, of course):

```
tony@home:515 <17:04:52> ~/IdeaProjects/SomeProject
$ gedit ~/.bashrc
```

I first noticed the issue when linking my project to my remote git repo. I expected the following (not a real repo, of course):

```
$ git remote add origin https://tony@bitbucket.org/tony/someproject.git
```

But instead got (note that it even overwrote part of my PS1):

```
project.gitte add origin https://tony@bitbucket.org/tony/some
```

The commands still work, even with this visual oddity.

**tl;dr** When I have long commands that exceed a single line, the second line overwrites the first. Any ideas why?

Comment: Already has an answer in the [thread you linked to](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/49896/28235): "Test should not be counted as a visible character and should be included between `\[` and `\]`."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wrap your colour escape sequences in `\[` and `\]` (like mentioned in the answer to the question you linked to) to mark them as non-printable characters.
That way, `bash` won't count them towards the prompt length when calculating after how many characters it should move to a new line.

```
STARTCOLOR='\e[0;36m'
ENDCOLOR="\e[0m"
export PS1="\n\[$STARTCOLOR\]\u@\h:\! <\t> \w\n\$ \[$ENDCOLOR\]"
```