# Bash first line rewriting

Tags: bash, prompt

I am having the same issues as [these](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49891/bash-overwrites-the-first-line-ps1-bash-prompt) [guys](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/216576/bash-overwrites-the-first-line-when-using-custom-ps1-prompt), but following the recommended advice does not seem to fix my issue. I know I am missing something.

Why does the below cause the first line to loop?

```
COLOR1="\[\e[38;5;15m\]"
COLOR2="\[\e[48;5;31m\]"
COLOR3="\[\e[48;5;240m\]"
COLOR4="\[\e[38;5;31m\]"
COLOR5="\[\e[48;5;214m\]"
COLOR6="\[\e[38;5;240m\]"
COLOR7="\[\e[38;5;0m\]"
COLOR8="\[\e[0m\]"
COLOR9="\[\e[38;5;214m\]"

function custom_prompt() {
    PS1="${COLOR1}${COLOR2} \u@\h ${COLOR3}${COLOR4}${COLOR1}${COLOR3} \w ${COLOR5}${COLOR6}${COLOR7}${COLOR5} $(__git_ps1 '%s ') \$ ${COLOR8}${COLOR9}${COLOR1}${COLOR8}  "
    VTE_PWD_THING="$(__vte_osc7)"
    PS1="$PS1$VTE_PWD_THING"
}
PROMPT_COMMAND=custom_prompt
```

Comment: You don't need a custom prompt function for that, simply setting a PS1 variable with the terminal control sequence codes is enough. This script doesn't loop.

Comment: What do you have in `__vte_osc7`? Without, this works as one would expect.

Comment: Just the default in F25... I was reading the man pages and the examples had it in there. Guess it is not needed.